# How do I flip characters or words like emacs' transpose?

Tags: normal-mode

On bash's readline in emacs mode, I recently discovered the [transpose](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transpose.html) functionality, giving me the opportunity to quickly fix a typo like

```
dc dir
```

to

```
cd dir
```

by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on the `c` character.

Is there something similar in Vi/Vim that lets me swap characters and words around?

Comment: You could certainly make a macro/binding that does this.  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_letters is an example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For characters, it's fairly simple: `xp` to swap the letter under the cursor with the following letter, and `Xp` to swap the letter under the cursor with the previous letter.

The `x` command deletes the character under the cursor, leaving the cursor on the next character.  The `X` command deletes the character just before the cursor, leaving the cursor on the same character it was on.

`p` puts (pastes) the last deleted or last yanked text just after the current cursor position.  (`P` puts it just before the current cursor position, so `xP` and `XP` both leave the text the way it was before you started.)

For swapping words, I'm not sure; perhaps someone else can answer that.  You can come close with `dawwP` (or remap it to be shorter) but that will break on several edge cases, for example near the end of a line.

Comment: If non-core solutions are acceptable then there is https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange which let's you not only exchange words but also whole regions http://vimcasts.org/episodes/swapping-two-regions-of-text-with-exchange-vim/

Answer (score 2):

## Word swap mappings for Latin languages

The word swap mappings from the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines) will not operate correctly on **words with accented characters.**

These mappings are adapted to work with (European) [ISO/IEC_8859-1 Latin-1 Supplement characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). This is done by substituting all instances of `\w` with `[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-]` and all instances of `\_W` with `\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-]`.

## Clearing of search highlighting

Furthermore, [the search highlighting is cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580359/2192488) where needed.
This is achieved by adding `:nohlsearch<return>` at the end of each mapping when needed.

Here is the end result:

```
" Use gc to swap the current CHARACTER with the next, WITHOUT changing the cursor position.
nnoremap <silent> gc xph

" Use gw to swap the current WORD with the next, WITHOUT changing the cursor position.
nnoremap <silent> gw "_yiw:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>

" Disable Alt+[menukey] menu keys (i.e. Alt+h for help)
set winaltkeys=no

" Use Alt + ← or Alt + h to swap the current WORD with the previous, keeping the cursor on the current word. This feels like "PUSHING" the word to the left.
nnoremap <silent> <A-Left> "_yiw?[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-]\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
nnoremap <silent> <A-h>    "_yiw?[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-]\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
" <A-h> corresponds to è

" Use Alt + → or Alt + l to swap the current WORD with the next, keeping the cursor on the current word. This feels like "PUSHING" the word to the right.
nnoremap <silent> <A-Right> "_yiw:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o>/[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+<CR><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
nnoremap <silent> <A-l>     "_yiw:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o>/[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+<CR><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
" <A-l> corresponds to ì

" Use g{ to swap the current PARAGRAPH with the next.
nnoremap g{ {dap}p{
```